# Flutter Error: FIROAuthProvider credentialWithProviderID:provider

Tags: ios, firebase, android-studio, flutter, ios-simulator

I have a flutter built app and would like to add firebase_auth and cloud_firestore. It used to work smoothly. Then I added the following two lines into pubspec.yaml:

```
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
```

and run packages get. Without doing anything else, if I run my project it gives the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           132.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2020-01-31 14:17:56.015 xcodebuild[41367:4940394]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008006-0007354C3EFA002E was NULL
    2020-01-31 14:17:57.763 xcodebuild[41367:4940338] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fbdeb156390), Baseduo, iPhone, 13.3.1 (17D5050a), 4be1310269eaf14dd153c6def229bddceaeebbe6> == Underlying device preparation errors ==
    2020-01-31 14:17:57.763 xcodebuild[41367:4940338] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fbdeb156390), Baseduo, iPhone, 13.3.1 (17D5050a), 4be1310269eaf14dd153c6def229bddceaeebbe6> -- Failed _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not locked by passcode.
    Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
    Code: 5
    Failure Reason: allowsSecureServices: 1. isConnected: 0. Platform: <DVTPlatform:0x7fbde662bd20:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fbde662bca0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>>. DTDKDeviceIdentifierIsIDID: 0
    --
    2020-01-31 14:17:57.763 xcodebuild[41367:4940338] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x7fbdeb156390), Baseduo, iPhone, 13.3.1 (17D5050a), 4be1310269eaf14dd153c6def229bddceaeebbe6> == END: Underlying device preparation errors ==
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/Baseduo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.15.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:505:38: error: no known class method for selector 'credentialWithProviderID:IDToken:rawNonce:accessToken:'
          credential = [FIROAuthProvider credentialWithProviderID:provider
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/Baseduo/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.15.4/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:514:38: error: no known class method for selector 'credentialWithProviderID:IDToken:rawNonce:'
          credential = [FIROAuthProvider credentialWithProviderID:provider
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    2 errors generated.
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

There is also no response on Flutter Doctor:

```
/Users/Baseduo/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-TR)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.7 at /Users/Baseduo/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 9f5ff2306b (4 days ago), 2020-01-26 22:38:26 -0800
    • Engine revision a67792536c
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Baseduo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.0.beta.2

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Baseduo             • 4be1310269eaf14dd153c6def229bddceaeebbe6 • ios • iOS 13.3.1
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • 954398E8-1CB7-4189-B2E6-84E9F87BB94A     • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I could not find any action to resolve that and appreciate for your answer.

Thank you,

ps: I have used the same action into my other apps and no problem exists.

ps2: It works for Android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Running `pod update` in the ios directory fixes the problem (at least until next time).  See [this bug report](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1679).

Comment: No, it does not work. I already (and now once again) run ```pod repo update``` then ```sudo gem install cocoapods``` and then ```pod setup```. This does not solve my problem unfortunately.